# How to set up QuotaGuard qgtunnel on pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere, quotaguard

I am working on using QGTunnel on pythonanywhere to connect to my exchange online server and send emails using that. I have followed the setup steps as found on QuotaGuard website but one confusing part for me is where they wrote that we should change the code that starts up the application in the Procfile file. My question now is, as pythonanywhere does not have a Procfile, how can we achieve this step to Setup qgtunnel on pythonanywhere, or does that step only apply to heroku users

Thank you

I was thinking editing the wsgi file on the pythonanywhere Web tab, but I don't know exactly where to prepend the bin/tunnel in the file,and if I really need to

Comment: From a scan of the QGTunnel docs, I think it's unlikely that you will be able to use it on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: Okay, if you don't mind could you tell me specifically why you think so, which of the steps do you think cannot be implemented on python anywhere, is there an alternative solution that works on pythonanywhere to obtain static IP for email sending through exchange online server